# Console-based Guess the Number

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, number-guessing-game

I started learning Python and wrote my first program. This is a console game based on guessing the number. Can you take a look and tell me if I'm doing it right or give me any advice? Here is the code: https://github.com/theriseq/GuessTheNumber

Is it a good way of doing this or can I simplify it?

Thank you.

**main.py**

```py
from can_convert import check
import random

welcome_msg = """Welcome to GuessTheNumber Game!
I\'m thinking of a number between 1 and 100.
Can you guess this number?

[?] Type \'pass\' to exit game.
"""
print(welcome_msg)

number_to_guess = random.randrange(1, 101)
attemps = 0

while True:
    user_inp = str(input("Your choice: "))
    if user_inp != "pass":
        if check(user_inp):
            attemps += 1
            # print('is int')
            if int(user_inp) < number_to_guess:
                print("Your guess is too small.")
            elif int(user_inp) > number_to_guess:
                print("Your guess is too high.")
            else:
                print("Correct! You won the game!")
                print(f"Attemps: {attemps}")
                break
        else:
            print('Enter numbers only!')
    else:
        break
```

**can_convert.py**

```py
def check(to_check):
    try:
        int(to_check)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: Please edit your title to be on-topic, aka claim what the code does, as opposed to the currently very generic title.

Comment: Welcome to CR SE! Alex Povel is right that you need to rename the question, but the question body looks ok, and I'll try to post a response if work's not too busy this morning!

Comment: Technically we need the challenge description to be inside the question body, but a number-guessing-game is as common as FizzBuzz nowadays. Please note this for future questions though, good luck.

Comment: @AlexPovel Titles don't make questions on or off-topic. A bad title gets a downvote, but not a close vote.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list of found issues, in order of occurrence:

- importing from your custom `can_convert` is fine. You should stick to modularization like that for bigger projects. However, here, it actually seems to be in the way of things. It checks if the string can be converted, but does not actually do any conversion. We later have to do the conversion again anyway. This can be combined.
- Currently, the welcome message and actual `random` range can deviate. You already know what `f`-strings are, so they should be used to keep that in line.
- Use `randint` to include both bounds, as opposed to `randrange`, which would stop one short of `upper_bound`, as you already noted.
- `input` will already return a string, no need to convert via `str`.
- By inverting the logic in checking for `"pass"`, a whole block of indentation can be spared. Just check if `user_inp == "pass"` and `break` if `True`. All following code can be one level less indented, since no `else` statement is required.
- Now for the main logic. The `try` block has moved here, away from the import. Notice that the logic is still the same. However, we assign to `number` immediately without checking first. If this fails, the `except` block is triggered.

  - Note that `int("2.2")` will also be a `ValueError` despite `"2.2"`, to humans, clearly being a number. So the error message should specify `whole` numbers to be more precise.
  - The added `else` block is run if no `exception` was raised, so in the normal game.
  - `number` is now available, so no need to call `int` conversion repeatedly.

  Keep `try` blocks short and concise and never leave an `except` statement bare. You did this fine! Lastly, try to not nest `try/except` blocks.
- There was a typo for `attempts`.

```py
import random

upper_bound = 100
lower_bound = 1

welcome_msg = f"""Welcome to GuessTheNumber Game!
I'm thinking of a number between {lower_bound} and {upper_bound}.
Can you guess this number?

[?] Type 'pass' to exit game.
"""
print(welcome_msg)

number_to_guess = random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound)
attempts = 0

while True:
    user_inp = input("Your choice: ")
    if user_inp == "pass":
        break
    try:
        number = int(user_inp)
    except ValueError:
        print('Enter whole numbers only!')
    else:  # no exception occurred
        attempts += 1
        if number < number_to_guess:
            print("Your guess is too small.")
        elif number > number_to_guess:
            print("Your guess is too high.")
        else:
            print("Correct! You won the game!")
            print(f"Attempts: {attempts}")
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

You've done a great job demoing a variety of patterns and tools. I'll add two more things you could benefit from learning early:

- [Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) [hints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558710/10135377). Function headers are almost always clearer with type hints, and you need them if you want to use a tool like [MyPy](https://github.com/python/mypy).
- [The main method pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22493194/10135377).
- (Usually I'd also advocate for recursion when someone's demo project is a REPL game like this, but in your case I don't think it would improve this code.)

Other stuff:

- Usually it's better to avoid exceptions when you have other options. While you could do what you're doing here by other means, you've done a few things that make me like your `check` function: It's concise, it bundles away a discrete bit of functionality, and you're catching a narrowly defined exception class.
- Unfortunately, it's a little clunky to have a function that just tells you if `int(x)` threw an exception, just so you can call `int(x)` on the next line. You have many other options; I'd be fine with `def check (user_input: str) -> Optional[int]:...`, but then you *must* use `if x is [not] None:...` later.
- Depending exactly what the function in question does, either `validate` or `sanitize` would probably be better than `check`.
- I lied: another new thing to learn: [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). In particular, a `while` loop that increments something is always begging to get replaced with a `for` loop. In this case, since we want to keep going "as long as it takes", we need a lazy infinite iteratable: `itertools.count(0)`.

  - In order to make that work, we'll need to separate out the "that input was invalid, try again" logic into a separate loop (or recursive function).
  - And then if you teach yourself [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) you could write `for (try_number, user_input) in zip(itertools.count(0), yielded_user_input()):...`. Fun times!

Comment: "Usually it's better to avoid exceptions when you have other options.", do you have an example? One replacement for exceptions can lead to an abundance of `isinstance`, `hasattr`, `issubclass` or similar checks (*Look Before You Leap*), which is mostly more verbose with little added benefit. See also [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/).

Comment: @AlexPovel Where EAFP may be Python-idiomatic, (1) there are exceptions and (2) it's not my personal style. Consider the difference between `try: dict[k] except KeyError` vs. `dict.get[k]`, where I would prefer the latter.

Comment: People throw exceptions and catch exceptions all the time and it's _fine_. But I do claim that you should always _consider_ other options. If what you're trying to say is `if is_valid(x): y(x) else: z()` then you wouldn't want to write `try: y(x) except Barr: z()`. Also, while it seems trite to say "There are a lot of ways you can do exceptions badly", people really do make mistakes, and other patterns really do have fewer pitfalls.

Comment: Okay, both these are good points.

Comment: "The main method pattern" links to MyPy, Is that supposed to be a different link?

Comment: @lights0123; Fixed!